# Enterprise Architect what packages have I checked out?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am using Enterprise Architect with Microsoft Team Foundation Server for version control.

I have a fairly complicated package structure and I want to be able to check at a glance what packages I have checked out.  The only way I can see to do this is to manually look through my model hierarchy checking the icons on a package level.  This is obviously tedious and error prone.

Many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to list all the packages I have checked out?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784581/how-to-list-all-the-packages-i-have-checked-out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enterprise Architect has a built-in query which exactly meets your needs:

1. Open the "Find in Project" window by Ctrl+F. A search window will be displayed.
2. On the top you will see a "search:" dropdown list which by default is set to "Simple".
3. Choose the last option from drop down list: "My Checked-out Packages".
4. Press the "Run" button or F5 to get the list.