# How to find all checked out packages in Sparx Enterprise Architect?

Tags: sql, enterprise-architect

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784581/how-to-list-all-the-packages-i-have-checked-out) except I'd like to find *all* checked out packages (and ideally list who checked them out) rather than just my own.

*Am assuming there must be a way of doing this by modifying the SQL provided by EA's [Search Builder](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/navigate_search_and_trace/creating_filters.html) from the answer to the linked question - just couldn't figure out how...*

Comment: From the question, have you checked Uffe and my answer? Using EA scripts should be sufficient to perform what you need. You can use EAPackage.Owner to get username that performed the check out.

Comment: Thanks - think I may have found a way to do this using just SQL - see answer posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my current attempt adapted from the built in "My checked out packages" search query:

```
SELECT 
t_object.ea_guid AS CLASSGUID, t_object.Object_Type AS CLASSTYPE,t_object.Name AS Object, t_object.Object_Type AS [Type], t_object.Stereotype, t_object.Scope,t_object.Status, t_object.Phase, t_object.CreatedDate, t_object.ModifiedDate, MID(t_package.PackageFlags, INSTR(t_package.PackageFlags, 'CheckedOutTo') + 13, INSTR(MID(t_package.PackageFlags, INSTR(t_package.PackageFlags, 'CheckedOutTo') + 13), ';') - 1) AS CheckedOutTo
FROM
t_object, t_package
WHERE
t_object.Object_Type='Package'
AND
#DB=Other#t_object.PDATA1 = cstr(t_package.Package_ID)#DB=Other#
#DB=ORACLE#t_object.PDATA1 = to_char(t_package.Package_ID) #DB=ORACLE#
#DB=OPENEDGE#cast(t_object.PDATA1 as char(25)) = cast(t_package.Package_ID as char(25))#DB=OPENEDGE#
#DB=ASA#t_object.PDATA1 = cast(t_package.Package_ID as char)#DB=ASA#
#DB=SQLSVR#t_object.PDATA1 = cast(t_package.Package_ID as char(25))#DB=SQLSVR#
#DB=MYSQL#t_object.PDATA1 = t_package.Package_ID#DB=MYSQL#
#DB=POSTGRES#t_package.Package_ID = t_object.PDATA1::text::int#DB=POSTGRES#
AND
t_package.PackageFlags LIKE '*CheckedOutTo=*'
ORDER BY t_object.Name
```

*The hashed bits are macro string replacers as documented [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/navigate_search_and_trace/creating_filters.html).*

Comment: Can you please add some documentation so that I can understand properly the code you've posted? What is the `#` character? Thanks in advance!

Comment: OK - see modified answer

Comment: Thanks. Which DBMS you use for Enterprise architect? Oracle?

Comment: It's a [Search Definition](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/navigate_search_and_trace/creating_filters.html). Seemed not to work in the end - have kept the code here to record it as a starting point in case it may be of help.